# jquery on() method doesnt work with td child?

Tags: html, jquery

I'm working on a calendar. It's working, and its possible to enter new appointments through a jQuery call and a PHP post.

But, I put in an adjust button and a delete button as an image to the appointment, which is nested as span in a table cell. I can select the `td` class and add appointments, but I can't select the adjust and trash buttons, except when I disable the `on()` event on the `td` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.adjust').on('click', function() {
    $('#popupsubmit').val("Aanpassen");
    $('#afspraakinfo').text('Afspraak aanpassen:');
    $('#popup').show(800);
  });

  $('.trash').on('click', function() {
    $('#popupsubmit').val("Verwijderen");
    $('#afspraakinfo').text('Afspraak verwijderen:');
    $('#popup').show(800);
  });

  $('.inhoud').click(function() {
    var trimTime = $.trim($(this).parent().text());
    var aanVang = moment(trimTime, "HH:mm").format('HH:mm');
    $('input[name="vanaf"]').val(aanVang);
    var startTime = trimTime;
    var newTime = moment(startTime, "HH:mm").add(50, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');
    $('input[name="tot"]').val(newTime);
    $('#popupsubmit').val("Toevoegen");
    $('#afspraakinfo').text('Nieuwe afspraak:');
    $('#popup').show(800);
  });
});
```

```css
.inhoud {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: left;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<tr>
  <th class="headcol" id="11:00:00">11:00</th>
  <td class="inhoud">
    <span class="overlay" id="2" style="z-index:1000;top:50%;height: 83%;">xxxx van 11:30:00 tot 12:20:00</span>
    <span style="z-index:1001;position:absolute;top:50%;right:0px;">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" style="cursor:pointer;" class="adjust">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/cc0000" style="cursor:pointer;" class="trash">
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The HTML code is dynamically generated.

Comment: this happens because `adjust` and `trash` elements are children of `td`, so when you bind the `td` to the click event, it will fire wherever you click inside the td.

Comment: you could bind the TD only, `$('.inhoud').click(function(e) {` and use `e.target` to check exactly which element was clicked

Comment: For accessibility you should be using button elements, or at least give your images the `aria-role="button` attribute.